# Как мне проверять на null при чтении (readUTF()) второй параметр конструктора класса в лямбда выражении?

Tags: java, лямбда-выражение

```
        case EDUCATION:
            return new OrganizationSection(
                    readCollection(dis, () -> new Organization(
                            new Link(dis.readUTF(), dis.readUTF()),
```

Мне нужно проверить второй аргумент конструктора класса Link на null, и если он "null" - String, то присвоить null, а если не null, то записать значение считанное dis.readUTF().
Как можно это сделать через переменную, когда в лямбда выражении они должны быть финальными?

Answer (score 2):

Можно обернуть в `String.valueOf`

```
String.valueOf(dis.readUTF())
```

Если передаваемый объект будет `null`, то вернётся строка `"null"`

Comment: Пардон, ошибка в вопросе. Исправил. Правильно "Мне нужно проверить второй аргумент конструктора класса Link на null, и если он null, **то присвоить null**, а если не null, то записать значение считанное dis.readUTF()."

Comment: @matua куда присвоить null? во второй параметр? ну так если dis.readUTF() вернёт null, то он и передастся в Link, зачем ещё что-то делать?

Comment: и если он "null"

Answer (score 1):

```
    `case EDUCATION:
        return new OrganizationSection(
                readCollection(dis, () -> {
                    String url;
                    return new Organization(
                            new Link(dis.readUTF(), (url = dis.readUTF()).equals("null") ? null : url),...}));`
```